# Dictionary syntax error while getting top 20 results using dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax-error

I have an input file, each line of which has a set of words. Next i take a query and compute similarity scores between each line of the input file and the query. I am trying to do this by using dictionary, keeping the maximum size of dictionary as 20(to get top 20 results, if sorted by value)
But i'm getting the following syntax error:

```
File "retrieve.py", line 47
result.item()[20].key()=temp
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

My code is:

```
images=open("jcnout","r")
res=open("result","w")
while linecount>0:       //linecount is the num of lines in file images
    line=images.readline().split()
    ////compute score for each line
    if (len(result)<20):
        result[str(line)]=score
    else:
        if(len(result)==20):
            result = sorted(result.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
            if(result.item()[20].value()<score):
                result.item()[20].key()=str(line)
                result.item()[20].value=score
                result = sorted(result.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    res.write(result)
    linecount-=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you **can't** assign to a function call:

```
result.item()[20].key()=str(line)
```

which is exactly what you're trying to do!

as I don't understand how you got the `result` object, I can't give you a better advice on how to change the value of the `result.item()[20]`. But if it is a dictionary you'd better do:

```
result.item()[20][str(line)] = score
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function here and trying to assign the returned value another value:

```
result.item()[20].key()=str(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i got my mistake